# Javascript Object.getOwnPropertyNames returning empty?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary

I have a Map<string, mixed> in JS and do the following:

```
console.log('Data: ', dataMap);
console.log('Object: ', Object.getOwnPropertyNames(dataMap));
```

and the first line prints out what I expect:

```
0: {"data_field1" => 4}
1: {"data_field2" => "test"}
...etc
```

but when I use Object.getOwnPropertyNames, Object.keys or Object.entries there is nothing returned - it is just an empty array. Why would this be happening if the data is clearly there? Is there an alternative I can use to get access to all the properties/keys of that Map?

Comment: What _exactly_ is `dataMap`?  It looks like it's an array, not an object.

Comment: `dataMap.keys()`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries

Answer (score 0):

You said you're using a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), so you're probably looking for [#keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/keys) or the like.